# Am I missunderstanding CC.Move?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I made this code and it works, however it's more of a teleport then a smooth movement.

```
        if (totalVelocity >= 0.05f)//If true Player has swing their hand
    {
        //getting the direction that the player is facing
        direction = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        //move the player using character controller
        characterController.Move(speed * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(direction, Vector3.up));
    }
```

I was wondering, am I misunderstanding `Move` or ...?

Comment: I think it is intended to be used for a single frame update, so if it is a larger distance/time you would have to split it up into shorter pieces over time

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm confused on how I would do that though. I am very small brain aha

Comment: I am not a Unity programmer, but I think there is something called a MonoBehaviour that you can add to your project and register with the engine. It has an `Update` method that gets called by the Engine during game ticks AFAIK(which you might have to configure). I think the intended way is to interact with it in there. Or maybe I don't get what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe you speed is just too high?